# Odoo - Disable selection option in tree view for some rows based on condition

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, xml, odoo, odoo-12

How to disable selection option in tree view for some rows based on condition ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Provide one unique id to each and every checkbox.

Use Jquery or javascript onLoad or document.ready method to disable the checkbox. create for loop and write simple disable code for your matching value.

document.getElementById("myCheck").disabled = true;

I m not sure about odoo. but I have a little bit of knowledge about odoo. you have to set a data field for this if dynamic data come from Database.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/views.html#lists), there is no multi editing feature.

The checkbox selector is added in [_renderSelector](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/views/list/list_renderer.js#L617) function of the `ListRenderer` widget, so you need to override it to disable the checkbox based on condition.

In the following example we disable the selection checkbox when the `state` (hard coded) field value is equal to `draft`.

***Example:***

```js
odoo.define('web.CustomListRenderer', function (require) {
"use strict";

    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');

    ListRenderer.include({
        _renderRow: function (record) {
            var self = this;
            var tr = this._super(record);
            tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('disabled', record.data.state == 'draft');
            return tr;
        },
    });
});
```

You can pass an evaluation domain in the action context, then evaluate the domain in the `_renderSelector` function using the current record value.

We initialize the [domain](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/core/domain.js#L27) in `init` function and use the [compute](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/web/static/src/js/core/domain.js#L41) function to get the evaluation result:

```js
odoo.define('web.CustomListRenderer', function (require) {
"use strict";
    var ListRenderer = require('web.ListRenderer');
    var Domain = require('web.Domain');

    ListRenderer.include({
        init: function (parent, state, params) {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            if (state.context.selection_domain) {
                this.domain = new Domain(state.context.selection_domain, state.context);
            }
        },

        _renderRow: function (record) {
            var self = this;
            var tr = this._super(record);
            if (record.evalContext.selection_domain) {
                tr.find("input[type='checkbox']").prop('disabled', this.domain.compute(record.data));
            }
            return tr;
        },
    });
});
```

You need to add the `selection_domain` to the action context:

```
 {..., 'selection_domain': [('state', '=', 'draft')]}
```

Check the [Assets Management](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management) documentation to see how to add the above JavaScript code to the web assets, you can also see an example in [Adding files in an asset bundle](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#adding-files-in-an-asset-bundle) section.

Comment: am not proficient with JS. Gonna try this Today and will update if it works. 
Due to time constrain I did like changed color of the row to grey to trick customer.